# What do they mean by "missing required libarary"?

Tags: eclipse

I just started making a Minecraft Mod using Eclipse and just finish setting up my all the stuff needed like: **"gradle"**. After launching Eclipse, I got two errors.

1. Project 'Minecraft' is missing required libraries: 'C: Users....';
2. The project cannot be built until build path errors resolved.

**What do these errors mean? What can I do to solve these errors?**

I am just a beginner, so I don't really understand so much. Please teach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm done with this. I will just post an answer here. Don't accept it.

So what that means is that Eclipse is looking for a file "x.jar" in your `.gradlew` folder. However, it cannot find it. So what happens if you need a class from there? Obviously your code won't compile right? Therefore eclipse complains and won't compile the code. So the way to add back the library is this.

1. Check that your `build.gradle` file has the right syntax and it has no errors like missing curly braces.
2. Run `gradlew clean`.
3. Run `gradlew setUpDecompWorkspace` / `gradlew setUpDevWorkspace`. (As you guessed, the first gives source code, the second doesn't)
4. Run `gradlew eclipse`. (Sets the classpath)
5. Back in eclipse, go to your project and click <kbd>F5</kbd> first, then click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd> on mac).
6. Now all your errors should be fixed!

---

Note:
If on linux/mac, add a `./` in front of the `gradlew ...`.
Also do `chmod 700 gradlew`